# Position RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Всем привет.
Подскажите как можно вытащить позицию выбранного итема в RecyclerView?
Ситуация такая: есть два фрагмента, в первом отображается список объектов, второй фрагмент содержит более подробное описание объекта. И вот вопрос как во втором фрагменте вытащить позицию RecyclerView из первого фрагмента по клику на итем?

Comment: Попробуй реализовать все через interface :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Например при переходе на другой фрагмент можно передавать позицию через bundle:

```
val detailFr = DetailFr()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putInt("pos", pos)
detailFr.arguments = bundle

fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainer, detailFr).commit()
```

ну и в целевом фрагменте ловить:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false)
        val bundle = arguments
        val pos = bundle.getInt("pos")



...
}
```

[вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate) по данному вопросу и [статья](https://medium.com/better-programming/a-new-way-to-pass-data-between-fragments-a5d32acc34e7) на данную тему